# Start intent when pitch us between 0 and 135 Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sensors

in this image (taken from web) that summarizes what i want to achieve in my Android app, but i have some problems.

[image]

Basically when the user has the smartphone in position 1 (bottom) the phone change activity, and when the smartphone position in the 2, another activity should be active in the screen.

This is the class i use for the gyroscope and it works good, but if i try to start an Intent after the "orient.setText()" it doesn't work. 
Hope that someone can help me.

**EDIT: This is the full working code.**

```
    package com.orientation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class Orientation extends Activity {
    private TextView orient;
    private Sensor sensor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        orient = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orient);
        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        List<android.hardware.Sensor> sensorList = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        if (sensorList.size() > 0) {
            sensor = sensorList.get(0);
        } else {
            orient.setText("Orientation sensor not present");
        }
        sensorManager.registerListener(orientationListener, sensor, 0, null);

    }

    private SensorEventListener orientationListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
                float azimuth = sensorEvent.values[0]*180/Math.PI;
                float pitch = sensorEvent.values[1]*180/Math.PI;
                float roll = sensorEvent.values[2]*180/Math.PI;

                if (pitch < -45 && pitch > -135) {

                    orient.setText("Top side of the phone is Up!");
                    Intent top = new Intent(Orientation.this, ActivityA.class);
                    startActivity(top);

                } else if (pitch > 0 && pitch < 135) {

                    orient.setText("Bottom side of the phone is Up!");
                    Intent bottom= new Intent(Orientation.this, ActivityB.class);
                    startActivity(bottom);



                } else if (roll > 45) {

                    orient.setText("Right side of the phone is Up!");

                } else if (roll < -45) {

                    orient.setText("Left side of the phone is Up!");
                }

            }
        }

    };
}
```

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.orientation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityB"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_b" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityA"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_a" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the TYPE_GYROSCOPE return angles are Radian angles, use:

```
        float azimuth = sensorEvent.values[0]*180/Math.PI;
            float pitch = sensorEvent.values[1]*180/Math.PI;
            float roll = sensorEvent.values[2]*180/Math.PI;
```

Second, 
You do not start `Activity` as i can see, just trying to set text.
Edit:
If that is your indicator for phone's orientation , make an Intent at the right place:

```
    package com.orientation;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.hardware.Sensor;
    import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
    import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
    import android.hardware.SensorManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.List;

    public class Orientation extends Activity {
        private TextView orient;
        private Sensor sensor;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            orient = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orient);
            SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
            List<android.hardware.Sensor> sensorList = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
            if (sensorList.size() > 0) {
                sensor = sensorList.get(0);
            } else {
                orient.setText("Orientation sensor not present");
            }
            sensorManager.registerListener(orientationListener, sensor, 0, null);

        }

        private SensorEventListener orientationListener = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
                if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
                    float azimuth = sensorEvent.values[0]*180/Math.PI;
                    float pitch = sensorEvent.values[1]*180/Math.PI;
                    float roll = sensorEvent.values[2]*180/Math.PI;

                    if (pitch < -45 && pitch > -135) {

                        orient.setText("Top side of the phone is Up!");
                        Intent top = new Intent(Orientation.this, <yourTopclass>.class);
                        startActivity(top);

                    } else if (pitch > 0 && pitch < 135) {

                        orient.setText("Bottom side of the phone is Up!");
                        Intent bottom= new Intent(Orientation.this, <yourBottomclass>.class);
                        startActivity(bottom);



                } else if (roll > 45) {

                    orient.setText("Right side of the phone is Up!");

                } else if (roll < -45) {

                    orient.setText("Left side of the phone is Up!");
                }

            }
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I had already tried to start an activity after the orient.setText(), but the app crash with this error:

Error:(57, 21) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous SensorEventListener>,Class<ActivityB>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous SensorEventListener> cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous SensorEventListener> cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: Did you declare your activity on AndroidManifest?

Comment: Can you please Edit your post with the current code? including the intents

Comment: I added the current main and the manifest as requested, thanks

Comment: Try this :Intent bottom= new Intent(Orientation.this, ActivityB.class); and also for ActivityA

Comment: Ok, the intent call you suggest solved the problem! Thanks a lot. I edited the code with the solution, please edit also your first reply so i can flag it as accepted answer.